# Loop continuously through an array onClick and render each element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I want to loop through an array onClick and render the elements one by one as long as the array length and when I reach the end of the array to start from the beginning again. For example I have 2 arrays as below and I want to loop through the first array as long as the length of the second array but every time the first array to start from the beginning after the end of it:

```
const a = [a, b, c, d, e] and const b = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]

changePlayers = () => {
  index++; // if this is the last item then go to first item
  index = index % a.length
}
```

I am trying to render each element one at a time from the first array `a[0]`

This is for a truth or dare game that I am trying to make.

Comment: How do you call this function and what value do you give it for `index`?

Comment: I want to give the value of the first array but whatever I have tried so far didnt worked. let val = a[0]

Comment: Use a separate function to loop through, once `for` loop executed, self invoke the function

Comment: Please edit your question to post the code you have tried so far, and read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is not clear what elements you are trying to render.

Comment: I have edit the question and I hope is more clear now what I want to do. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one loop. Run your loop and iterate for the length of the second array. Have a variable outside the loop (I named it `indexTracker`) that will keep track of the indexes of the first array. Then in an if-statement in the loop, if the index for the first array goes out of bounds, reset the `indexTracker`

```
const arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];

// This will track the indices of the first array
// We'll reset this when we go out of bound
let indexTracker = 0;

// For the length of the second array
for(var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {

  // If index does *not* exist for arr1
  if(!arr1[indexTracker]) {
    // reset the index tracker
    indexTracker = 0;
  }

  // Do whatever you want with arr1 values here.
  // You can return / render them, etc. I'm just console logging.
  console.log(arr1[indexTracker]);

  // Note: You can still use variable i to access values in arr2. I.e.:
  // console.log(arr2[i]);

  // Increment the indexTracker
  indexTracker++;
}
```

Comment: it is showing always the first element of arr1 and if i increase the indexTracker by 1 is showing the 3 element of the arr1

Comment: Oops, I forgot to increment the indexTracker! I updated my answer to show where to do it. When I run the above, the output I get it: `a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c` (on different lines of course). is that the output you're looking for?

Comment: I saw it but is not what im looking for. The result that im looking is to show a single element from the arr1 on every click and then when i reach the end of arr1 to loop from the beginning of arr1 until the end of arr2. example output: click output a, click output b, click output c, if end of arr1 start from beginning of arr1 click output a, click output b, click output c until the end of arr2. I will try to create a codepen and share it here. thanks again

Comment: this is the codepen that i created so it will be easier to explain what i mean https://codepen.io/panoscool/pen/LBwKXj?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

```
 var numbers = [4, 9, 16, 25];
 var number1 = [3, 8, 15];
 var x = "";
 numbers.forEach(function(val){
   number1.forEach(function(val2){
      x += val2+" - "+val+ "<br>";
     });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the response I got when I tried in W3school.

HTML:

```
 </head>
 <body>

  <button onclick="myfunction()">Click Me</button>
  <div id='demo'></div>
  <script>
       function myfunction(){

       var numbers = [4, 9, 16, 25];
       var number1 = [3, 8, 15];
        var x = "";
        numbers.forEach(function(val){
        number1.forEach(function(val2){
               x += val2+" - "+val+ "<br>";
            });
         });
         document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = x;

        }
    </script>

    </body>
   </html>
```

Output

---

```
3 - 4
8 - 4
15 - 4
3 - 9
8 - 9
15 - 9
3 - 16
8 - 16
15 - 16
3 - 25
8 - 25
15 - 25
```

Comment: this is showing the output from both arrays and what im looking is to show a single element from the arr1 on every click and then when i reach the end of arr1 to loop from the beginning of arr1 until the end of arr2. example output: onClick output a, onClick output b, onClick output c, if end of arr1 start from beginning of arr1 onClick output a, onClick output b, onClick output c until the end of arr2. I will try to create a codepen and share it here

Comment: this is the codepen that i created so it will be easier to explain what i mean https://codepen.io/panoscool/pen/LBwKXj?editors=0010